# Adding jars to Tomcat classpath

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, dependencies, war

I have an Eclipse project running on Tomcat, with my dependency jars sitting in the WEB-INF/lib directory. Everything is great. But the war file created on export is huge, and I'm going to need to send it back and forth to the test server, which will be time consuming. It seems like a waste.

So I put all my dependency jars in a folder, dependency_jars, in my file system, and configured the build to point there. The build works, but when I run it (still on my local machine) the app is throwing runtime errors.

Reading around, I went to the project properties and added the jars to the Web Deployment Assembly. Now the runtime works, but the exported war once again has all the jars packaged with it.

So how do I have my dependencies available for the runtime environment, without having Eclipse package them inside the war?

Comment: Maybe this bit of info can make it more clear: I'm looking for something like the options you have on Eclipse when exporting a runnable jar. Under "Library handling" there's a radio button to "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR." This separates the application code from the dependencies, so that everything is nicely structured.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution but what I did is configure Tomcat to use an external library, put the dependency jars there, and then let eclipse create the war with everything in it, explode it from the command line, remove the dependency jars, repackage the war, and finally send it out.

Well, definitely not an elegant solution. But it works. Here are the steps:

1. Configure Tomcat to use an external resources library. Go to tomcat_home/conf/catalina.properties and add your directory under the comment that starts with "List of comma-separated paths defining the contents of the "common" classloader..."
2. Export war through Eclipse.
3. Explode the war (pun probably merited here:) jar -xvf MyWar.war
4. Remove your dependency jars (which are now in the external directory from step 1 above.)
5. Repackage the war: jar cvf MyWar.war WEB-INF